# How could I explain how a “three body or more system” orbit works?

Tags: science-fiction, orbital-mechanics

Three-body orbits are said to be unstable and non-existent. Star Wars introduced us to Utapau which is likely highly unstable. Yet in that universe it works. What are some possible explanations for this to possibly exist? I’m trying to think of a good explanation for my story. [image]

Comment: The issue with 3+ body orbits isn't that they're inherently unstable, the issue is that there isn't a general closed form solution. There are stable 3 body orbits, there are stable n body orbits. Explaining the orbits of your planets is more of a writing issue than a worldbuilding one. In Star Wars they probably didn't explain it since they decided that a fantastic environment was more worthwhile than killing the story with a physics lecture. We'd need to know the particular orbital characteristics of your planets to be able to meaningfully respond to this question.

Comment: The question cannot be anwered because it does not include even the smallest amount of data about the desired system. For a trivial example, the Sun-Earth-Moon three-body system is quite stable. For another example, the Sun-Jupiter-Io-Europa-Ganymede-Callisto **six** body system is also quite stable. VTC as needs more details.

Comment: Well it’s 5 body. Utapau, 2 moons and the sun. 

I read that the moons could not be that close to a planet or they would crash into them.

Comment: Nice artwork (courtesy of Lucasfilm & co.). But can you better define what the question is and how it involves worldbuilding - else it's likely to be closed as either needing details and clarity or as not about worldbuilding because it's about Star Wars.

Comment: **CLOSE VOTERS** I was tempted to VTC this question because it probably violates the [help]'s book rule. However, the [help/on-topic] states, "World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, in short, everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire universe you want to build." While this Q could use some refining, **it's exactly the kind of question we like.** And as I thought about it, it's not too ambiguous, either. What makes a 3-body system unstable? Based on that knowledge, what (\*continued\*)

Comment: ...rationalizations can be construed or derived? Oftimes we get *way too locked up* in Real World science. Maybe I'm wrong and one of our Celestial Mechanics gurus can explain why this Q is out of bounds... but all things considered, I'm not convinced this question should be closed or down voted. **However...** user73829, you need to *clearly understand* that we ***do not answer*** Qs about 3rd party or commercial worlds. I can squint my eyes and read a "this is about my world!" intent to your question - but I'm squeezing them pretty tight. If you're asking about Star Wars, this is off-topic.

Comment: Finally, @user73829, had you taken the time to read even the mouse roll-overs for the tags you listed, you would have read that you *cannot* use [tag:hard-science], [tag:science-based], and [tag:science-fiction] on the same question. You are allowed to use *only one.* They serve to scope the answers. I selected [tag:science-fiction] because, frankly, a [tag:hard-science] answer to a question asking how to rationalize breaking the laws of physics in the Real World is a pretty high expectation.

Comment: @JBH: There are well-known real-world examples of stable three-, four-, five- or six-body systems. That is, a multi-body system is not necessarily unstable. Unfortunately, we cannot say anything about the querent's system, because they have cunningly chosen to tell us nothing about it.

Comment: @AlexP The querent is looking for a way, in his/her universe, to generally rationalize a condition. That problem isn't solved by tweaking their magically one-and-only system (assuming this isn't an off-topic Star Wars question) until it fits the stability rules of the Real World. Let's broaden our perspective a bit and remember that an imaginary world can exist happily in the mind of the querent and all they're asking for is a bit of help rationalizing it so they don't go stark raving mad.

Comment: Good grief. Closed. The whole point of this site is to help people break the rules of physics and we closed this question because it's not Real World enough for us. I'm actually ashamed of this Stack.

Comment: @user73829 I'll vote to reopen if you [edit] your question to make this a worldbuilding question and clearly NOT a question about the Star Wars universe.

Comment: I count 4 worlds in that picture...

Answer (score 2):

**It Works Just Fine.**

How does the stable three body system work? It works just fine.  Gravity deforms  spacetime to makes the suns and planets and moons go around and around each other for billions of years without escaping. Like how Jupiter goes around the Sun and a dozen moons go around Jupiter. That's one stable binary system. Another type is the [P-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_binary_star_systems) system where two large masses orbit each other and then a smaller mass orbits the two biggies from much further away.

You see ALL two-body systems are stable. SOME three-body systems are unstable. But some are stable. So you are in luck my friend.

Comment: "ALL two-body systems are stable..." Define 'stable'. A two-body planet and meteor system seems to have a strange sense of 'stability'.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond How many meteors are we talking?

Comment: Take the moon for example. Examples of 'stable' two-body orbits all over the surface.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond: The two-body planet-and-small-body system is absolutely stable. Not the model's fault that the small body has chosen a trajectory which intersects the surface of the primary, thus achieving eternal stability by means of lithobraking.

Comment: @ 
AlexP Like I requested, define 'stable'. There is 'before cusp stable' and 'after cusp stable., but the cusp itself?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond "Stable" in terms of orbits is defined as being that the system will remain predictable to near-infinity barring any perturbing influence.  Three-body orbits are said to be "unstable" because you cannot, in most cases, solve the equations of gravity analytically so that you can predict the system's state at any point in time. In effect, you have to run the equations out to that time. Two body orbits reduce to simple Keplerian mechanics and can be approximated with conic sections for all time. In a 3 body system, you must solve the equations of gravity iteratively.

Comment: @stix
 An interesting lesson. All well and good. But a meteor slamming into the surface of a planet, does not meet your definition of stable. At the time of the point of impact, your 'conic section for all time- becomes totally irrelevant. All two-body systems are NOT stable.  Some end up being VERY unstable.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond You asked for a definition of "stable." One was provided. All two-body *orbits* are unconditionally stable. All two body problems can be reduced to a closed form, unlike three or n-body problems, which are chaotic (an antonym of "stable"). That is obviously what OP is referring to with the statement "all two body systems are stable."

If you are going to simply dismiss the definition you asked for and merely substitute it with your own, why ask the question in the first place?

Comment: @stix
 A cusp is NOT 'unconditionally stable'. That is the difference between theoretical and applied physics. Theoretical physics is always in its own model of reality, not reality itself. Sometimes, the models just do not work in reality - too many false assumptions about reality.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond You are reaching for something to disagree with.

Comment: @Daron
 I am not the one doing the disagreeing.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond There you go again lol.

Comment: Let me give you the facts, instead of your conjecture. A cusp is the spot on a curve where the variables change, and the curve takes a new direction or another line intersects the curve. For instance, in terminal velocity, the cusp on the speed curve occurs when air resistance becomes the dominant factor rather than gravity. Any n-body system is stable between cusps, and many n-body systems do not have cusps. .However, any n-body system CAN have a cusp - a spot on the curve where a variable changes or another system dominates.

Comment: In a three body system, there is a more pronounced likelihood (probability) of cusps over a two-body system, at a point where the gravitational field of one object becomes more dominant in the overall model. However, between these cusps, the system is stable. But there are also many two-body systems that also experience cusps, so it is not absolute that ALL two body systems are ALWAYS stable. My example of one body colliding with the other body (a cusp) is one example among many. Theoretical physics generally ignores cusps, as they are generally something that occurs in specific applications.

Answer (score 1):

Three-body orbits aren't unstable (necessarily), they're just chaotic. That is, it's impossible to predict how the orbits will develop over a modest timescale, but it's very likely that they all remain in orbit around each other. A three-body system is "unstable" in the sense that it's not periodic, so it doesn't settle into predictable behavior, but the objects will remain in orbit together.

No when I say "modest" I mean in astronomical time. Unless your story takes place over millions of years, your orbit will be basically stable. If it does take place over millions of years, then you can essentially make up any halfway plausible orbit development and there will be some initial condition that makes it work.